# Unauthorized response on GetReportInGroupAsync PowerBI Embedded API call using Service Principal

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm attempting to embed Power BI reports into my .Net Core application, however I'm unable to get a valid response back from the request. I'm using the Microsoft.PowerBI.API package and an azure app registration with service principal.

As far as I can tell, I have set up the AAD and Service Principal up with the correct permissions following the instructions here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal

I caught the part where you have to add the AAD/Service Principal to the security group before adding that security group to the admin settings in Power BI Admin Portal.

Here's my code snippit I'm using:

```
var AuthorityUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/";
var ResourceUrl = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api";

var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(AuthorityUrl);
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = null;
var credential = new ClientCredential("application_id", "application_secret");
authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceUrl, credential);

using (var client = new Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.PowerBIClient(new Uri("https://api.powerbi.com/"), new TokenCredentials(authenticationResult.AccessToken, "Bearer")))
{
    var report = await client.Reports.GetReportInGroupAsync(new Guid("workspace_id"), new Guid("report_id"));
}
```

I successfully get the token back from the `AcquireTokenAsync` call, however when getting the report I get an unauthorized.

Here are the permissions of my AAD/Service Principal in Azure:
[image: azure aad api permissions]

Here is my Request/Response that I captured with Fiddler.
Request:

```
GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{workspace_id}/reports/{report_id} HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer {access_token}
User-Agent: FxVersion/4.6.28207.03 OSName/Windows OSVersion/Microsoft.Windows.10.0.18362. Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.PowerBIClient/3.14.01300.0002
Host: api.powerbi.com
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: RequestId
request-redirected: true
home-cluster-uri: https://wabi-west-us-redirect.analysis.windows.net/
RequestId: {request_id}
Date: Thu, 10 Sep 2020 16:23:07 GMT
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Service Principal to work for any embedding, you need to enable Service Principal option in Power BI Admin portal and then, add it to the Power BI workspace.

Please check the following once:

1. Check if service principal is enabled under Admin portal in Power BI service.
   Follow [step 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal#step-3---enable-the-power-bi-service-admin-settings) onwards
2. If things don't work for you after following the above step, try embedding with the developer [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/.NET%20Core/Embed%20for%20your%20customers)

Besides, based on your code it looks like you are using ADAL library for authentication. Microsoft [recommends to use MSAL library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-migration#:%7E:text=We%20now%20recommend%20using%20the,Azure%20AD%20identities) for authentication with Azure AD entities.
Also, you can use certificate instead of app secret for service principal authentication. ([Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal-certificate))

Comment: I actually figured this out prior to your answer. We had already hooked up the PowerBI side correctly, the isue was with our authentication. We switched to the MSAL library and were able to get it to work! Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the exact same thing here:
[PowerBI - getting EmbedToken - Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72209123/powerbi-getting-embedtoken-unauthorized).
and I still can't get it working.  If I am logging in my application, not a specific user, then WHICH group or user needs to be added to the power bi workspace?  Adding an application there is not an option